# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS does not detect monitor

Tags: monitor

I have Hewlett-Packard HP Compaq 8200 Elite with these specifications:
Processor : (Intel® Core™ i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8)
Graphic: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 2000 (SNB GT1)
I have install Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
The only monitor that it detect is an old HP monitor, it is not detecting any monitors.
I have bought 3 new monitors and still they are not get detected.
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: xrandr -listmonitors